# how to embed Turn by turn navigation on my google

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to embed turn by turn navigation in my android application.please give me a tutorial or an idea for how to do this.thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Did you implemented this? please help me I have to implement same like this

Answer (score 3):

If you are not fixed on using google maps you can use an SDK based on OpenStreetMap (the Wikipedia version of maps)

There are a couple of good SDK providers out there:

- [skobbler](http://www.skobbler.com/) (now Telenav) has an SDK which is able to render maps & display turn by turn navigation on your Android phone. It also supports offline mode. See more [here](http://developer.skobbler.com)
- [OsmSharp](http://www.osmsharp.com/) also does map rendering and turn by turn navigation. You can pull their code from [github](https://github.com/xivk/OsmSharp)
- [MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com/) has a nice [map & routing engine](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api) for Android. I think you could also use their routing service with Mapbox maps (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300866/routing-between-points-with-mapbox) as a starting point). I don't think they can do offline mode
- [Cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com/) has a [navigation SDK](http://cloudmade.com/products/nav-sdk) for Android. Their documentation shows how it can be achieved but I couldn't find a way of quickly downloading the SDK & sample projects

As a reference you see the OSM [list of frameworks](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks)

Answer (score 3):

I thought that there was no way to embed turn-by-turn instructions into my application, but I was totally wrong. The Google Maps API V2 actually does offer turn-by-turn instructions. Check out Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsSteps).

I used the code given in [this library](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionAndPlaceLibrary) to get basic routing information. I then added the following method to `GoogleDirection.java` to return a list of turn-by-turn instructions:

```
// getInstructions returns a list of step-by-step instruction Strings with HTML formatting
public ArrayList<String> getInstructions(Document doc) {
    ArrayList<String > instructions = new ArrayList<String>();
    NodeList stepNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (stepNodes.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < stepNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentStepNode = stepNodes.item(i);
            NodeList currentStepNodeChildren = currentStepNode.getChildNodes();
            Node currentStepInstruction = currentStepNodeChildren.item(getNodeIndex(currentStepNodeChildren, "html_instructions"));
            instructions.add(currentStepInstruction.getTextContent());
        }
    }
    return instructions;
}
```

This approach doesn't offer real-time updates telling you when you've reached a new turn, but it works well and serves my needs. I use my `getInstructions` method with an `instructionsToString` helper method, which concatenates the instructions with an HTML line break. That code is [here](https://gist.github.com/VinceFior/7d9b9ccd9c7dbf658eb1) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in your Activity:

```
double latitudeDestination = 52.377028; // or some other location
double longitudeDestination = 4.892421; // or some other location
String requestedMode = "walking" // or bike or car
String mode = "";
if(requestedMode.equals("walking")) {
  mode = "&mode=w";
} else if(requestedMode.equals("bike")) {
  mode = "&mode=b";
} else if(requestedMode.equals("car")) {
  mode = "&mode=c";
}

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse(String.format("google.navigation:ll=%s,%s%s", latitudeDestination, longitudeDestination, mode)));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Actually, that will fire Google's navigation app. The author wanted to embed the turn by turn inside his app.

Comment: @Bolhoso, I agree. I saw a few SO posts like these and concluded that what the asker wanted was impossible, but it turns out it's totally possible. Check out my answer for embedded turn-by-turn instructions. :)