# Routing between points with MapBox

Tags: ios, routes, gps, mapquest, mapbox

I know that similar questions have been asked here before but none of them really answered my question and I am under pressure to finish my project by a deadline.

Basically I am writing an application that will show online and offline maps.

I am currently using MapBox SDK for the viewing of both offline and online maps, however, MapBox does not currently offer a routing solution. So I am looking for a way to do it.

The main problem seems to be that there isn't just one SDK that will offer online OSM maps,  offline OSM maps AND routing so I was wondering would I be able to use MapBox to handle the maps and then use MapQuest to get the route? Is this possible? Is it recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could use another engine for routing and just plot it as an `RMAnnotation` with an `RMShape` in the MapBox SDK.

Comment: Great, I'll take this approach so. Thank you for the reply.

Is routing something that you see being implemented into the MapBox SDK anytime soon? 

Love the SDK by the way, it's very nice to use.

Comment: Yes, it's on the roadmap, but no ETA as of yet.

Comment: Hi Is it possible to get user current location in offline  mapbox sdk.?

Comment: is it possible to find the shortest path among the given routes on mapbox in ios?