# in-app turn by turn navigation routes data source, waze for example?

Tags: ios, navigation, maps

I am planning to create a turn by turn navigation system, with some extra social features. the problem is that I didn't find a good routes provider, or the method that i can use to add the "turn by turn" navigation feature. Google map is no help on iOs, does waze has public API ?? I kinda want big range of countries to be supported, so the quality of the routes provider is important.
One more thing, after i (( somehow )) get the route information from some provider, how do I implement the routing from within the app ??

Any suggestion will be of great help, thanks in advance.

Comment: read this from apple -> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html

Comment: Thanks, i came across this article before, but will this do like facebook authorisation ?? (( open the Mapp app for a couple of seconds then go back to my app ?? ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an SDK which runs on top of OSM (OpenStreetMap).
The maps are not quite the same grade as Google Maps, Navteq or TomTom but in some countries the are as good (if not better) - e.g. UK, Germany. And the maps are getting better.

Here are a couple of good SDK providers that give you turn by turn navigation :

- [OsmDroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) with [OSMBonusPack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) - this option should be free but it might not look as good as the other SDKs
- [Skobbler](http://www.skobbler.com/) (now telenav) has an SDK which is able to render maps & display turn by turn navigation on your iOS phone. It also supports offline mode. You have to reach out to them personally if you want a copy of the SDK (they should have a free plan). In the end you should be able to get your app to look like their own [app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/gps-navigation-2-satnav-by/id329340711)
- [OsmSharp](http://www.osmsharp.com/) also does map rendering and turn by turn navigation. You can pull their code from [github](https://github.com/xivk/OsmSharp). Should be free
- [MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com/) has a nice [map & routing engine](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api) for Android. I think you could also use their routing service with Mapbox maps (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300866/routing-between-points-with-mapbox) as a starting point). I don't think they can do offline mode. I don't know if you have to pay for MapQuest (couldn't find on the website), Mapbox has a free plan.
- [Cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com/) has a [navigation SDK](http://cloudmade.com/products/nav-sdk) for Android. Their documentation shows how it can be achieved but I couldn't find a way of quickly downloading the SDK & sample projects. You'll have to request a quote for a price

As a reference check the OSM [list of frameworks](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks)